Outlook Change message class
Is there a way to change message class so I can have specialized view of tht READ message in VBA?? Would a C# Addin do it?  And reset to the basic "IPM.Note" on send?
I want to add the folder path so when I Read mail I can see the folder (And eventually click to jump there). I Tried ThisOUtlookSession Object inspectors and the WithEvents to try to set and save prior to opening but it uses the default IPM.
Option Explicit
Const otlIPMcustFormClass As String = "IPM.Note.CustomReadForm" ' Custom form class for reading

Sub UpdateSelectedMailForm()
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Get the currently selected items in the explorer
    Set objSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    ' Loop through each selected item
    For i = 1 To objSelection.Count
        ' Check if the selected item is a MailItem
        If TypeOf objSelection.Item(i) Is Outlook.mailItem Then
            Set mailItem = objSelection.Item(i)
            
            ' Update the MessageClass to the custom form class
            mailItem.MessageClass = otlIPMcustFormClass ' Use your custom form class constant
            
            ' Save the changes
            mailItem.Save
            mailItem.Display

            ' Optional: Display a message or log the update
            ''MsgBox "Updated the form for: " & mailItem.subject, vbInformation
        Else
            ' If it's not a mail item, notify the user
            MsgBox "Selected item is not a MailItem. Please select an email.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Outlook likes caching its items for the performance reasons. There is no way to control its cache. As a general rule of thumb, dereferencing an item, opening a different item, and then the first one is enough. Restarting Outlook would definitely work.
But why would you want to do that on the fly? And why do you need to change the item class? If you want to display an extra piece of intimation / button, a ribbon control or a task pane/form region would do a much better job


I want to add a form locally that I can show data on the front of the form -particularly the Message IPM, so I can see data for debugging.


But why would you want to change the message class? Are you trying to use a custom Outlook form (linked to a particular message class) in VBA? Custom Outlook form is not the best solution for what you are trying to achieve.
